# Dynamically import/use images from collection markdown with Astro assets?

Tags: markdown, astrojs

As an example, I have an [Astro app](https://astro.build/) with a [collection](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/) `/collections/artworks` where each `artwork` specifices a cover image via the frontmatter `cover: '../assets/artworks/1-hello/cover.png` - the file lies at `/src/assets/artworks/1-hello/cover.png`. I am trying to use [Astro's asset support](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/assets/).

Then in my template, I am looping through all the artworks and have `<Image width={400} src={artwork.data.cover} alt={artwork.data.coverAlt} />` which does not work and fails to find the file.

Trying to import it inline seems to fail `<Image width={400} src={import(artwork.data.cover)} alt={artwork.data.coverAlt} />` with the error "Received unsupported format `undefined` from `undefined` ", assuming that it's just not resolving.

However, if I import the image explicitly with the same path as specified in the markdown, it works:

```
import cover from "../assets/artworks/1-hello/cover.png"
<Image src={cover} ... />
```

How can I loop through a collection and dynamically import images specified in the markdown accordingly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use images in Markdown frontmatter with Astro’s assets feature, you need to use the [`image` helper](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/assets/#update-content-collections-schemas) in your content collection schema.

Assuming your current schema looks something like this:

```js
// src/content/config.ts

import { defineCollection, z } from "astro:content";

export const collections = {
  artworks: defineCollection({
    schema: z.object({
      cover: z.string(),
    }),
  }),
};
```

You need to update the `schema` to be a function, and use the `image` parameter as the schema type for `cover`:

```js
// src/content/config.ts

import { defineCollection, z } from "astro:content";

export const collections = {
  artworks: defineCollection({
    schema: ({ image }) => z.object({
      cover: image(),
    }),
  }),
};
```

This will import the image for you behind the scenes, so that you can pass `artwork.data.cover` directly to the `<Image>` component.

Comment: Wow this worked absolutely perfectly, even with the new assets functionality and the `~/assets` alias. Thank you.

Comment: How can we import multiple images, e.g. a cover image for a gallery of images?

Comment: To add multiple images: `cover: z.array(image()),`